# Naming method: send_auto_reply() vs send_autoreply()

Tags: python, naming-conventions, naming

I am unsure whether to name a method `send_auto_reply()` or `send_autoreply()`.

What guidelines can be applied here?

It's Python, but AFAIK this should not matter.

Comment: `autoreply` is not a word by itself so I think `send_auto_reply` would be more apt.

Comment: I see that this question gets down-votes. Please help me to improve. What's wrong with this question? Is there a better site for questions like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such word as `autoreply` so you should name it as `send_auto_reply`